# Aligned vector, matrix, vector, multiplication

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, matrices

I already have something that looks good to me, but the latex implementation is hideous. Any ideas for how this could be done in a cleaner way?

```
\[
    \frac{dz}{dt} = 
    \raisebox{1.02em} {$
        \boldsymbol{[}\begin{array}{cc}
            1 & -1 \\
        \end{array}\boldsymbol{]}$
    }
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}
        \frac{\partial \underline{y}}{\partial \underline{x}} & \frac{\partial \overline{y}}{\partial \underline{x}} \\ [0.5em]
        \frac{\partial \underline{y}}{\partial \overline{x}}  & \frac{\partial \overline{y}}{\partial \overline{x}} \\
    \end{array}\right]
    \left[\begin{array}{c}
        1  \\[0.5em]
        -1 \\
    \end{array}\right].
\]
```

[image: render]

Comment: Is the example what you think looks good, or what you think looks hideous? I would personally prefer the first vector to be aligned centrally, but I get why one might prefer pushing it up. And the `\partial` symbols are not aligned horizontally which I don't love, I guess they're being pushed up by the `\underline{}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I think that the code looks hideous. I'm happy with way the rendered image looks. I wanted to align the tops of all the braces and have equally sized braces because that's how I think most people would write it. This misalignment of the `\partial`s is a nightmare.  I didn't notice. Any fixes for that?

Comment: I think the bigger brackets may be an improvement as well.

Comment: The most immediate improvement would be to use upright differential `d`s. The next one to write the expression as a trace.

Comment: Why should I not use `\partial`? To clarify, `y=f(x)` where `f: R^2 -> R^2` and the underlines and overlines access the lower and upper bounds of the intervals. I'm working with interval arithmetic. This is as part of a chain-rule derivative computation where each expression is a term.

Comment: Don't worry about the “d”. Contrary to what @Schrödinger'scat thinks, mathematicians are happy to use an italic “d” for the differential and have *mathematical* reasons to justify the choice.

Comment: @egreg Wrong. And you know it.

Comment: The partial derivatives are fine. Italic differential d's are not. "Let $d$ be a distance. It's time derivative, $\frac{dd}{dt}$, satisfies ... " Not really. You also write `$\sin t$` and not `$sin t$` to typeset a sine.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Tell it to Walter Rudin, for instance.

Comment: @egreg It has been your standard strategy, given the lack of arguments, to mention some famous people who also do it wrong. There are many more famous people who do it right. But this does not matter. The above is a clear argument. If you really want to write the time derivative of `$d$` as `$\frac{dd}{dt}$`, that's your choice, but please do not propagate this as the correct way. We both know it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting alignments with so inhomogeneous objects requires a bit of manual adjusting.

I raised the first row vector “by eye”; it would be possible to compute the amount of raising exactly, but I did it just to show that it's really awful and unhelpful for the reader. Why the top and not the bottom? There's no reason for choosing either, so the right place is at the center.

More importantly, I added some shorthands that help both in typing and in reading code.

Some “phantoms” make the objects align nicely.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newenvironment{rowvector}
 {\bm{[}\begin{matrix}}
 {\end{matrix}\bm{]}}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\ol}{\overline}
\newcommand{\ul}{\underline}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{dz}{dt} =
\raisebox{3ex}{$\begin{rowvector} 1 & -1 \end{rowvector}$}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \pder{\ul{y}}{\ul{x}} & \pder{\ol{y}\vphantom{\ul{y}}}{\ul{x}} \\[0.5em]
  \pder{\ul{y}}{\ol{x}} & \pder{\ol{y}\vphantom{\ul{y}}}{\ol{x}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \vphantom{\pder{\ul{y}}{\ul{x}}} \\[0.5em]
 -1 \vphantom{\pder{\ul{y}}{\ul{x}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
\frac{dz}{dt} =
\begin{rowvector} 1 & -1 \end{rowvector}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \pder{\ul{y}}{\ul{x}} & \pder{\ol{y}\vphantom{\ul{y}}}{\ul{x}} \\[0.5em]
  \pder{\ul{y}}{\ol{x}} & \pder{\ol{y}\vphantom{\ul{y}}}{\ol{x}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \vphantom{\pder{\ul{y}}{\ul{x}}} \\[0.5em]
 -1 \vphantom{\pder{\ul{y}}{\ul{x}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although a number of the answers gave excellent solutions, I accepted this because it was the best for _my_ question. The code is clean and the result is in the same style as my solution, but with multiple improvements (e.g. the bracket alignment and spacing looks better imho). I have no idea what did it, but even the partials look aligned.

Comment: @Jesse Look in the code for `\vphantom` that inserts an invisible object with the same vertical size of what's specified in the argument.

Comment: Very clever. `\pder{\ul{y}}{\ul{x}} & \pder{\ol{y}\vphantom{\ul{y}}}{\ul{x}} \\[0.5em]`

Answer (score 5):

I would use `bmatrix` environments instead of generic `array` environments, and I would not raise the row vector above the baseline.

Using `\overline` and `\underline` may be an acquired taste. To my taste, though, the lines produced by these macros look really heavy, even domineering. Using `\bar{...}` and `\underaccent{\bar}{...}` (`\underaccent` is courtesy of the `accents` package) provides a lighter-looking solution; see the second row belo2. In that solution, I insert a couple of (typographic) struts (called `\bstrut` in the code) to fine-tune the positions of the numerator terms `\partial{\bar{y}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,accents}
% Create a typographic (bottom) strut:
\newcommand\bstrut{\vphantom{\underaccent{\bar}{y}}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{dz}{dt} 
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
       1 & -1 
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
       \frac{\partial\underline{y}}{\partial\underline{x}} & 
       \frac{\partial\overline{y}}{\partial\underline{x}}\\[1ex]
       \frac{\partial\underline{y}}{\partial\overline{x}}  & 
       \frac{\partial\overline{y}}{\partial\overline{x}}
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
       1 \\ -1 
   \end{bmatrix*} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
       1 & -1 
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
       \frac{\partial\underaccent{\bar}{y}}{\partial\underaccent{\bar}{x}} & 
       \frac{\partial\bar{y}\bstrut}{\partial\underaccent{\bar}{x}}\\[1.25ex]
       \frac{\partial\underaccent{\bar}{y}}{\partial\bar{x}}  & 
       \frac{\partial\bar{y}\bstrut}{\partial\bar{x}}
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
       1 \\ -1 
   \end{bmatrix*}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was my initial solution except for a few very nice touches that you added like the little space before the period. I diverged from that initial approach because I wanted it to look like how I would have written it. Is this the standard solution (was my final rendered result unusual)? I see from your profile that you're quite a TeX guru.

Comment: @Jesse yes, it is the standard solution, and I would suggest you also use this style when writing by hand.

Comment: @Jesse - I may be reasonably good at TeX and LaTeX in general, but I would not claim to be a guru on the subject of linear algebra notation. That said, I've never seen in any  of my math textbooks row or column vectors that weren't centered on the math line. (The math line is an invisible line; it can be visualized as running through the middle of `=` symbols.)

Comment: @Mico Strang's textbook is an example, in the excerpt, his typographer shifts vectors and matrices up to align them (http://math.mit.edu/~gs/learningfromdata/dsla1-1.pdf). I think I gained my preferences from his textbooks. This solution is excellent though.

Answer (score 3):

I propose to use a single `blockarray`,  the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` to have medium-size fraction inside arrays, and the `diffcoeff` package, for a simple syntax for partial derivatives. I also replaced `\overline` with `\widebar`, which is a real math  accent from `mathabx (without loading the package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\newcommand{\mdiffp}[2]{\medmath{\diffp{#1}{#2}}}

\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\bigstrutjot}{0.75em}\diff{z}{r} = \begin{blockarray}

{@{}cc@{\hskip 0.65em}[cc][r]}
   \boldsymbol{[}\, 1 & -1\, \boldsymbol{]} &\bigstrut\mdiffp{\underline{y}}{ \underline{x}} &\mdiffp{\widebar{y}}{ \underline{x}} & 1\\%[2ex]
   & & \bigstrut\mdiffp{\underline{y}}{\widebar{x}} & \mdiffp{\widebar y}{ \widebar x } & -1 
\end{blockarray}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried a number of things, but finally settled on this.  I `\smash`ed the matrix elements and increased `\arraystretch` until the spacing look good.  Then I put the row vector into `\raisebox` and adjusted the alignment again by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.6}% increase until matrix looks good
\[
    \frac{dz}{dt} = 
    \raisebox{2.2ex}% adjust until ones are lined up
    {$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} 
       1 & -1
    \end{bmatrix}$}
    \begin{bmatrix}
       \smash{\frac{\partial\underline{y}}{\partial\underline{x}}} & 
       \smash{\frac{\partial\overline{y}}{\partial\underline{x}}}\\
       \smash{\frac{\partial\underline{y}}{\partial\overline{x}}}  & 
       \smash{\frac{\partial\overline{y}}{\partial\overline{x}}}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
       1 \\% \llap{\rule{1.5in}{0.5pt}}\\% to chaeck alignment
      -1
    \end{bmatrix*}\,.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a little goofy, but I think it's in a way cleaner. Slightly different result.

I use `\vphantom` to create space to line things up programmatically without using explicit numbers, and define a command which holds the taller of your partial fractions so you only need to change the spacing in one place.

I use `\bigl[` instead of `\boldsymbol{[}` (the `\boldsymbol` does not actually appear to do anything).

I line up the row vector with the center of the upper row of the other elements, rather than push it right to the top.

```latex
\newcommand{\partialfractall}{\frac{\partial \underline{y}}{\partial \underline{x}}}


\[
    \frac{dz}{dt} = 
    \begin{array}{cc}
    \bigl[\begin{array}{cc}
            1 & -1
        \end{array}\bigr] \\
        \vphantom{\partialfractall{}}
    \end{array}
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}
        \frac{\partial \underline{y}}{\partial \underline{x}} & \frac{\partial \overline{y}}{\partial \underline{x}} \\ [0.5em]
        \frac{\partial \underline{y}}{\partial \overline{x}}  & \frac{\partial \overline{y}}{\partial \overline{x}} \\
    \end{array}\right]
    \left[%
    \vphantom{\begin{array}{cc}
        \frac{\partial \underline{y}}{\partial \underline{x}} & \frac{\partial \overline{y}}{\partial \underline{x}} \\ [0.5em]
        \frac{\partial \underline{y}}{\partial \overline{x}}  & \frac{\partial \overline{y}}{\partial \overline{x}} \\
    \end{array}}%
    \begin{array}{c}
        \vphantom{\partialfractall{}} 1  \\
        \vphantom{\partialfractall{}} -1 \\
    \end{array}\right].
\]
```

[image: new result]